# Node.js recursive calls with q framework for multiple GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, q, deferred

after searching stackoverflow and the Q documentation I do unfortunately still not understand the q.ninvoke function. I wonder if someome could explain me how it works with my scenario:

I am GET-ing a result of a fetchXml request wich returns at most 5000 entries. I wanted to implement a method which calls itself (over a chain) until no pagingcookie is responded by the server anymore.

In the end all results should get concatinated over the recursion to the top of the recursion...

```
var tryReexecuteForNext5000Entries = function(entitySetName, fetchXml, args){
    var deferred = q.defer();
    var response = args[0];    
    var jsonBody = args[1];
    var fetchXmlPagingCookieResponse = jsonBody["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"];

    if(!fetchXmlPagingCookieResponse){        
        deferred.resolve(args);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var pagingArgs = getPagingArgs(fetchXmlPagingCookieResponse);
    var pageNumber = pagingArgs[0];
    var pagingCookie = transformCookieForFetch(pagingArgs[1]);
    fetchXml = injectPagingArgsIntoFetchXml(fetchXml, pageNumber, pagingCookie);


    getWithFetchXml(entitySetName, fetchXml)        //recursion!
         .done(function(bodyValue){
             args[1].value = args[1].value.concat(jsonBody.value).concat(bodyValue);
             deferred.resolve(args);
        }
        .fail(function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
        }));

    return deferred.promise;
}

function getWithFetchXml(entitySetName, fetchXml){
    return AuthProvider.retrieveToken()
        .then(createFetchOptions.bind(this, entitySetName, fetchXml))
        .then(addProxyToOptions)
        .then(executeRequest)
        .then(checkResponse)
        .then(tryReexecuteForNext5000Entries.bind(this, entitySetName, fetchXml))
        .then(onRequestSucceeded.bind(this, "successfully GET fetchXml against CRM"))
        .fail(onFail.bind(this, "webApiRequest.getWithFetchXml: failed to GET with fetchXml: \r\n"+fetchXml));
}
```

with this setup Q throws me "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Should work as followed:

- call getWithFetchXml
- retrieves JsonObject List1 and pagingtoken AND
- ===calls getWithFechXml²
- ===retrieves JsonObject List2 and pagingToken AND
- ======calls getWithFetchXml³
- ======retrieves JsonObject List3 **without** pagingToken
- ======returns the list
- ===appends List3 to List2 and returns it
- appends List2 to List1 and returns it

Comment: I think you need to trim your code down until you have some sense of what's causing that `TypeError`. We can't tell you what's causing it, but I see two bugs in your code: (1) you're using `concat()` but not assigning the result to anything. `concat()` returns a new array; it doesn't modify the original. (2) you are calling `done()` on the result of `getWithFetchXml()`, but the last `then()` in that function is `onRequestSucceeded`, so `bodyValue` is going to be whatever that returns (probably `undefined`?).

Comment: Which of these two functions is the one that's originally called to start the operation?

Comment: thank you! I edited the question maybe its now more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a stupid syntactical mistake... sorry for that, I have not setup my VisualStuidoCode for good feedback when developing javascript.

the problem was:

```
getWithFetchXml(entitySetName, fetchXml)        //recursion!
        .done(function(bodyValue){
             args[1].value = jsonBody.value.concat(bodyValue);
             deferred.resolve(args);
        }
        .fail(function(error){
            deferred.reject(error);
        }));
```

WRONG BRACKETS! should be:

```
getWithFetchXml(entitySetName, fetchXml)        //recursion!
            .then(function(bodyValue){
                 args[1].value = jsonBody.value.concat(bodyValue);
                 deferred.resolve(args);
            })
            .fail(function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
```

Here is my running code for recursive JavaScripts in Node.js:

```
function getWithFetchXml(entitySetName, fetchXml){
    return getWithFetchXmlRecursive(entitySetName, fetchXml, null);
}

var getWithFetchXmlRecursive = function(entitySetName, fetchXml, page){
    return AuthProvider.retrieveToken()
        (...)
        .then(tryReexecuteForNext5000Entries.bind(this, entitySetName, fetchXml, page))
        .then(onRequestSucceeded.bind(this, "successfully GET fetchXml against CRM"))
        .fail(onFail.bind(this, "webApiRequest.getWithFetchXml: failed to GET with fetchXml: \r\n"+fetchXml));
}

var tryReexecuteForNext5000Entries = function(entitySetName, fetchXml, page, args){
    (...)
    var fetchXmlPagingCookieResponse = jsonBody["@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie"];        
    var onRecursionSucceeded = function(bodyValue){
        args[1].value = jsonBody.value.concat(bodyValue);
        deferred.resolve(args);
    }
    var onRecursionFailed = function(error){deferred.reject(error);};

    if(!fetchXmlPagingCookieResponse){        
        deferred.resolve(args);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    (...)
    console.log("webApiRequest.tryReexecuteForNext5000Entries: there is more! starting recursive request with depth: " + (page-1));
    getWithFetchXmlRecursive(entitySetName, fetchXml, ++page)        //recursion!
        .then(onRecursionSucceeded)
        .fail(onRecursionFailed);

    return deferred.promise;
}
```